# Python resolving ~ as fully qualified path in simple string before any I/O function

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I need to write a simple data processing script.  I made a very simple script that just takes a file name from the program arguments from the command line and just prints the value of the first argument:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    fileName = sys.argv[1]

    print "File name is %s" % fileName
```

Then I run the program:  `myProgram.py ~/datadir/file.txt`

Since nothing tells python that the argument is actually a path, I am surprise that infers it itself and resolves the ~ into a fully qualified path and the program outputs:

`File name is /Users/<my_username>/datadir/file.txt`

However, I am able to work around that by wrapping the command line argument in quotes:

```
myProgram.py "~/datadir/file.txt"
File name is ~/datadir/file.txt
```

Since I am in the process of learning Python, I was wondering is someone could explain what drives this implicit resolution.  E.g. does it automatically assume anything starting with ~ is a path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not Python that resolves the `~` character into the home directory but your shell; since you are using Mac OS X, it is most likely `bash`. Adding quotes around the file name will stop the shell from resolving the `~` character so Python gets it "as is".

Incidentally, the `expanduser` function in the `os.path` module of Python is also capable of resolving `~` into the user's home directory.

Comment: oh so it was resolved by unix before it ever hit python...  ok, makes sense

Comment: @amphibient Strictly speaking, not by Unix, but by the shell.

Answer (score 2):

The `~` symbol is a convention in Unix and Unix-like systems, it has nothing to do with Python. It means: start this path relative to the current user's home directory.